# DbSet.Attach() only updates single table but not referencing ones

Tags: database, entity-framework, repository

I have two tables: `Word` and `Adjective`, both with some properties. Primary key of both tables is `ID`, `Adjective.ID` also references `Word.ID` as foreign key so there is a 1-1 relationship.

I also have a repository for any kind of table with an Update function.

```
public void Update(T entity) {
    var entry = DatabaseContext.Entry(entity);
    DatabaseSet.Attach(entity);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

I take a value from the database, convert it into a ViewModel looking like this (of course it's actually a little more complex):

```
public class WordModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OriginalWord { get; set; }
}
public class AdjectiveModel : WordModel {
    public string Translation { get; set; }
}
```

Then I alter the values of properties Word and Translation, convert and write it back. After conversion I have an object like this:

```
Word = {
    ID = 1
    OriginalWord = y
    Adjective = {
        ID = 1
        Translation = z
    }
}
```

Upon updating however, only one table gets updated.

`Database.Words.Update(Word)` only updates the OriginalWord value in the Word table,
`Database.Adjectives.Update(Word.Adjective)` only updates the Translation value in the Adjective table.
When running the updates for both tables sequentially I get an InvalidOperationException: **An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.**
Creating a new database entry works perfectly.

I cannot believe I have to update both tables on their own and then save the context for each. I have created the database Repository via a Tutorial that obviously didn't explain well enough what's going on with the DbSet and the DbContext, which leaves me a little helpless here.
Sadly I have no link (it is quite a while ago I created the database project)

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You entity Word contains an entity Adjective, it is then the root of the object graph. Now generally here's what you should keep in mind in the following situations :

---

#### All objects in the graph are new (new word and new adjective)

use `myDbContext.Words.Add(myNewWordObjectGraph);` to have the correct state you want.

---

#### Only root is new (new word and a pre-existing non modified adjective)

use `myDbContext.Entry(myNewWord).state = EntityState.Added;` to have the correct state you want.

---

#### Root is modified and *some* nodes are modified (word and adjective both exist in the DB and both have been modified)

use `myDbContext.Entry(myWord).State = EntityState.Modified;` ***and*** `myDbContext.Entry(myAdjective).State = EntityState.Modified;` to have the correct state you want. i.e. call `myDbContext.Entry(myObject).State = EntityState.Modified;` for each modified object in the graph whether it's the root or some other node.

---

#### Root is unchanged and/or Modified and *some* nodes are added, others are also unchanged and/or modified

use `myDbContext.MyRootObjectDbSet.Add(myRootObject);` ; this will mark all the objects in the graph as `EntityState.Added` ***including the unchanged and/or modified objects***. so the next call should be for each unchanged and/or modified object in order to correct its state : `myDbContext.Entry(myObject).State = ThisObjectSCorrectState;`.

I Hope that helps

---

### EDIT

1. Calling `DbSet.Attach(...)` just adds the object to the objects *tracked* by EF. If you modify an object before calling `DbSet.Attach(...)`, the modifications won't be persisted to DB when you call `SaveChages()`, so attaching an object **as is** before modification, calling `DbSet.Attach(...)` and then modifying the object is the way to make EF aware of the modifications.
2. Based on the way your update method's defined I would assume your repository looks something like this maybe?

//Not threadsafe as it contains a transient object 'DbContext'.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRespository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly MyDbContext context;
    public Repository(MtDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context
    }

    //...
    public void Update(T entity) {... }
    public void Commit() { context.SaveChanges(); }
}
```

I would suggest changing the update method to the following :

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

And this update method would be called for each object you updated in the graph using the same instance of the repository enclosing the DbContext.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Setting EntityState to Modify on the Adjective works. However, I figured DbSet.Attach(...) takes care of that. If it doesn't, what is it actually for? Also, isn't there any kind of automatic process, which updates all elements in the graph? Running through the related tables in every different table kinda kills the generic approach of my database access layer.